# UpdateView and linking to a user

Tags: python, django

I've been advised that when it comes to updating a user I should use Django forms rather than rolling my own. As such, I've turned to Django forms but hit a bit of a wall.

A user in my system is defined, partly, as so:

```
#models.py
class Freelancer(AbstractBaseUser):

    email = models.EmailField(primary_key=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    surname = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    university = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    verified = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    biography = models.TextField(default="")
    skills = models.ManyToManyField(Skill)
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
```

I have a URL:

```
#urls.py
url(r'^profile/$', views.Profile.as_view(), name="profile"),
```

And the view:

```
#views.py
class Profile(UpdateView):
    model = Freelancer
    fields = ['email']
    template_name_suffix = '_update_form'
```

The problem is that I need to tell the server what Freelancer I want to update. I've tried adding `(?P<pk>\d+)/` into the URL regex as I saw on a few tutorials but when I pass in the id of a Freelancer - as automatically created in the schema - it doesn't retrieve a Freelancer. Based on my model, what should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's a bad idea to use the email address as primary keys. What if a user changes their email address?

It might be a better idea to have `unique=True` for the email address, and let Django create the automatic primary key. Then including  `(?P<pk>\d+)/` in your url should work.

If you must use the email as the primary key, you need to change the regex from `(?P<pk>\d+)/`, which will only match digits, to something like

```
(?P<pk>[\w@.-]+)
```

The above might not catch *all* email addresses. I think Django contains a better character class, but I can't find it at the moment.

Comment: That's an incredibly good point. Sometimes I get lost when I've got something with the scale of Django, heh.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are just doing it in a wrong way.
Here is what you need to do:

First of all I'd recommend you to add a pk to your model, as having email as a `pk` is a bad idea.

1. Create a `url` for update view

An example:

```
url(r'^profile/(?P<pk>[\d]+)/edit/$',
        views.ProfileUpdateView.as_view(), name='edit_profile')
```

2. Create an `UpdateView`

An example:

```
class ProfileUpdateView(UpdateView):
    model = Freelancer
    fields = ['email']
    template_name = "profiles/profile_edit.html"
```

3. Create a template for the form

An example:

```
<form action="" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <input type="submit" value="Update" />
</form>
```

Now you need to add this link wherever you want:

```
<a href="{% url 'edit_profile' profile.pk %}">Edit</a>
```

When you vist the url you will go to update page.